# how to show 2 different fields in autocomplete textbox in php?

Tags: php, autocomplete

I am using this function to show fields in autocomplete and its working for me.

```
function finderschool_autocomplete($string) {
   $result = db_query("SELECT 
   * FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE '%$string%' AND type='school' LIMIT 10");

  $matches = array();
  foreach($result as $item) {
    $display = $item->node_title."[school]";
    $matches[$item->nid] = $display;
  }
  drupal_json_output($matches);
  exit;

}
```

But I need to show different values in autocomplete textbox. its showing me school name but I need to show school country as well. 
For example if user type i then its show indragandhi school.. But I want it should return india and indragandhi school.

Comment: Can you post the table content?

Comment: print_r($item); return me array.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following code. I am assuming that your country field is "country". IF not please replace [country] with your country field name.

```
  function finderschool_autocomplete($string) {
       $result = db_query("SELECT 
       * FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE '%$string%' AND type='school' LIMIT 10");

      $matches = array();
      foreach($result as $item) {
        $display = $item->node_title."[school]"." - "."[country]";
        $matches[$item->nid] = $display;
      }
      drupal_json_output($matches);
      exit;

    }
```